# Run BackgroundWorker after another one completed

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, multithreading

I want to start a `BackgroundWorker` after another one is completed. I'm not sure on how to write the code for it, so I don't really have anything to show.

I thought about writing it in the `RunWorkerCompleted`, but that seems like the wrong place to put logic for starting another worker.

Where and how should I do this?

Basically, I want to use the same worker, but to do something else. Like in step 1 it parses data from files and in step 2, after step 1 is completed, it should write the parsed data from memory to the database.

Comment: There's no point in starting another BGW.  Just have the first one also execute the step2 code after step1 is complete.  You could even directly call its DoWork() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a third party library for job scheduling is acceptable for you check out **Quartz.NET** and it's job listener mechanism described here http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html. If you want to implement it by yourself i'd use a single `BackgroundWorker` that would execute a set of jobs organised into a **Chain of Responsibility**, you can read more about this pattern here http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

You can instead use the .NET 4.0 [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class and then queue more work using [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately I only have .NET-3.5 on the machine the application will be running...

Answer (score 3):

It's probably best to use two different `BackgroundWorker` components. Start the second one in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler for the first one. That seems like a very reasonable way to do things. Just don't try to do it with a single `BackgroundWorker`.

As [Tudor mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703154/56778), you could use `Task`, but then you lose the convenience of `BackgroundWorker`, with its familiar event-oriented interface, progress reporting, and such.

Answer (score 3):

From your description it seems that the steps are related and sequential so I would implement it as a single BGW where the `DoWork` performs both steps with a call to `ReportProgress` between the parsing step and the write to the database step.

You can then handle the [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event that runs on the UI thread to perform any logic after the parsing step as finished, knowing that the worker is already writing to the database.

The [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) accepts an integer to identify the percentage completed of the background task and an optionally custom object. So in your `ProgressChanged` handler you need to have logic to interpret this progress information. In this case, being a two stepped job, you can just call `ReportProgress(50)`.

Comment: ReportProgress doesn't only accept an integer.  The overload that accepts an object is instrumental in giving rich feedback.

Comment: You're right, I checked MSDN and totally missed the overload. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow to use one background worker for multiple and sequental operations:

```
    private void DoBackgroundWork<T>(string name, Func<T> work, Action<T> onComplete)
    {
        lblCurrentOperation.Text = name;
        StaticClass.OnProgress = (p) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(p);
        T result = default(T);
        var handler = new DoWorkEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            result = work();
        });
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += handler;

        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler completedHandler = null;
        completedHandler = new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            onComplete(result);
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork -= handler;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= completedHandler;
            lblCurrentOperation.Text = string.Empty;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        });
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += completedHandler;
    }
```

usage:

```
            DoBackgroundWork("Loading resources",
            () =>
            {
                return DoWork();
            },
            (result) =>
            {
                //final UI operations
                Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(t => this.Invoke((Delegate)new Action(() => anotherOperationWithSameWorker())));
            });
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```